# SQL Server: backup error 112: not enough space on the disk - true or not?

Tags: sql-server, backup

Last night my weekly backup on SQL Server 2014, running on Windows Server 2012 R2, failed with the following error in the log:

> failed with the following error: "A nonrecoverable I/O error occurred on file "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\Backup\backup-xxxx.bak:" 112(There is not enough space on the disk.).

When I checked disk space I found there was still 1 GB free, and the .bak file looked ok, all 4GB of it, not compressed.

So I ran a RESTORE VERIFYONLY command on that file:

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = 'D:\MSSQL\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\Backup\backup_xxxx.bak'
```

that responded:

> The backup set on file 1 is valid.

So which version of the story should I trust?

Note: According to Pinal Dave (http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/04/14/sql-server-backup-randomly-failing-error-112-not-enough-space-disk/) the first error is not accurate, especially if using compressed backups.

Comment: Are you compressing the backup or not though?

Comment: Run `RESTORE HEADERONLY ...` to see what date the backup was taken.  Perhaps the backup is actually from the previous week.

Comment: Also if you didn't back up with INIT, the backup operation that caused the error might not have been the backup stored as file 1. SQL Server doesn't raise out of space issues for fun and games, it only does that when it actually comes across a space problem, in spite of whatever Pinal might say about it.

Comment: What Pinal is saying might be related to your scenario if you are using compression. Yes the way compression works for allocating space is bit different.  But the crux is during backup SQL Server is not able to find enough space and so it is failing.

Comment: @Molenpad: The backup is not compressed.

Comment: There is something suspect in the execution of the weekly full backup. The last times it ran successfully, there were two .bak files.   I suspect it may be running out of space for the second backup, though I am not aware of having requested a *second* full backup.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my bad. :-/  **SQL Server is correct on both accounts**.

The weekly full backup starts at 6 PM on Sundays, and the daily incremental backup starts at 8 PM. The weekly backup is still running when the daily incremental starts. The daily incremental records a .bak file that is the same size as the full, because ?? all indexes, statistics and so on have changed.

At this point, or rather, some two hours later, when it has finished reorganizing indexes and updating statistics, there isn't enough disk left for the full backup.

The incremental backup that I checked with RESTORE VERIFYONLY is ok.
The full backup was never created.

So now I have to choose between some options:

- start the Full backup a few hours earlier,
- skip the incremental on Sundays,
- (suggestions welcome ... )

Comment: Are you backing up your database to the same disk that hosts your data and/or log files for SQL Server? Let me count the ways this is a serious problem...

Comment: @Aaron: well spotted. This is the configuration I inherited, and I am learning the hard way...